# Why are my plated drills seen as non-plated by Eurocircuits?

Tags: pcb

I have drawn a PCB with gEDA suite version 20140316 and uploaded my exported Gerber files to Eurocircuits – I selected `Eagle` export format. Everything looks fine with the exception all drill holes are seen as non-plated instead of plated (I guess the name of my gerber file, aka `mypcb.plated-drill.cnc`) is not what Eurocircuits checks). Why is it so and how can I make sure drill holes are indeed plated?

Comment: The board house should have a list of fab files that they need and the file extension they expect. Drills are oftens specified in a .txt, its possible that .cnc is a plain text file with a .cnc extensions. You should go through the eurocircuit requirements to make sure your export is generating the files they expect. Its not uncommon to go through and rename the gerbers to match what the board house wants. The benefit of using a more expensive service is that they have an engineer/tech do this for you

Comment: @crasic Thanks. I'm still reading Eurocircuits recommendations and re-exported my PCB gerber files. Now the drilling information looks correct. It's all about finding the correct export options and including the correct layers with the correct information. Step by step I'm fixing issues, there's a lot to grasp but it's doing good so far.